# What are the implications of enabling CDN for our Organization asset library

Tags: sharepoint-online, development, administration, pnp

I run this command to configure an Organization Asset Library:-

```
Add-SPOOrgAssetsLibrary -LibraryURL https://contoso.sharepoint.com/templates  -OrgAssetType OfficeTemplateLibrary
```

we did this for the following reasons:-

1. We want to store templates for word and PowerPoint, **so all internal users and specified external users can use those library.**
2. so inside the document library >> we add everyone except external + 10 external users to have read access on the Organization library.

but the issue is that when i run the above command, CDN were enabled for our library.. so what is the implication of enabling CDN on the library? and could i achieve the above 2 requirements while disabling CDN ?

second question, if  i want to disable CDN can i modify this for our current Organization asset library?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding an organization assets library will enable a **content delivery network (CDN)** for your organization to provide fast and reliable performance for shared assets. You'll be prompted to enable a CDN for each organization asset library you add. For more information, see [Content Delivery Networks (CDNs)](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-365/enterprise/content-delivery-networks?view=o365-worldwide).

**`-CdnType`**：Specifies the CDN type. The valid values are **public or private**. If you don't specify the CdnType, it will **enable a private CDN by default**.

After the setup CDN can be disabled, but I don’t recommend disabling CDN at all for performance sake. Also notice that when library is demoted, CDN Origin setting is not removed.

---------------------- `Updated Answer` ------------------------

1.If your Organization asset library contains sensitive data, it is very reliable to use **Private CDN**.

2.**Private** origins within the Office 365 CDN provide private access to user content such as SharePoint Online document libraries, sites and proprietary images. **Access to content in private origins is secured with dynamically generated tokens so it can only be accessed by users with permissions to the original document library or storage location**.

The simplest option is grant everyone the **Read permission** to site hosting asset libraries to make sure that users consuming the assets have access to Organization asset libraries.

Your could grant "**Everyone except external**" group and the specific external users **Read permission** to the Organization asset library.

Comment: thanks for the reply... ok in my case i did not specify the `-cdnType` so the default will be private,, so the question is; if it is fine to have private cdn for sensitive data we have inside the Organization asset library? as inside this library we have organization templates and we only want them to be accessed by the users we define inside the document library permission settings, including internal and external users... is this fine to use private cdn in our case?

Comment: Hi, John John. I have updated answer under initial My Answer. Hope this can help you to solve issue. Have a nice day!